# Error in using .Net vncSharp Library : - vnc Host not found

Tags: c#, .net, vnc

I am using vncSharp library to connect remote desktop.
The sample source code i downloaded from [here](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/vncsharpexample-csharp-1.0-src.zip)

If i run that project by passing host name, it says check vnc host is running in client.
I am not able to able to figure it out.

My requirement is to view remote desktop without the remote system getting locked.

Please help on this regard.

**UPDATE**

Any other possibility to connect using `tscon.exe`

Comment: any possibility to achieve this by using MSTSCLib in .Net ?